# took her hand and held it tight/tightly

Tags: adverbs

> He took her hand and held it tight/tightly.

Would using "tight" here be bad grammar?

I did a search on Google that showed that "tight" was just as common as "tightly" in contexts like this, which surprised me because I only thought "tightly" was correct. Could someone please enlighten me.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary to see if "tight" can be used as an adverb?

Comment: [Some words](https://www.englishpractice.com/improve/words-adjectives-adverbs/#:~:text=Some%20adjectives%20formed%20by%20adding,quarterly%2C%20half-yearly%20etc.) can be used as both adjectives and adverbs.

Comment: held it tightly is fine.